# ggplot2 - how to fill nested polygons with colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, fill, polygons

I have > 100 nested polygons in a unique `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. I desire to plot them with `ggplot2` and **all of them need to be visible in the map**, i.e. overlaying larger polygons have to be in the background.

I found that I can achieve this by using `alpha = 0` within the `geom_polygon` function but **how can I assign a fill colour to each polygon?**

Here an example of my code with just 2 polygons:

```
library(ggplot2)
```

Read csv file with two shapefiles merged and then converted to data.frame with `fortify` from `maptools`.

```
#read csv file shape_1_2.csv
shape_1_2 = read.csv('shape_1_2.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#plot
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = shape_1_2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
             colour = 'black', size = 1, linetype = 'solid', alpha = 0)
```

And relative map:

[image]

**How can I fill with colour these two polygons?**

I tried to add `fill='black'` in both `aes` and `geom_polygon` but it doesn't work.

Thanks

---

Update

I am sorry but I realised that my example data contains NO nested polygons.

So starting from the following data.frame as per https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280671/r-create-multipolygon-from-overlapping-polygons-using-sf-package :

```
shape_df = data.frame(
    lon = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0.8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
    lat = c(0, 0, 1, 1.5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
    var = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3, 4 ,4 ,4, 4, 4)
)
```

And my plotting code (with `alpha=0`):

```
ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = shape_df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = var), 
                 colour = 'black', size = 1, linetype = 'solid', alpha = 0)
```

With relative map:

[image]

**How can I fill the different areas present in the map with one OR up to 4 colours so that the larger polygons remains in the background of the smaller?**

Comment: Please provide a _minimal reproducible example_ so that people willing to help easily can try out their code.

Comment: thanks. I put a Dropbopx link from where to download my example data.

Comment: How do you intend to mark the order of polygons? Do you have a way that you're measuring the area of each?

Comment: Hi, thanks. Good question..I already have the area of each polygon in a separate file. But what I need is just fill all of them with same colour AND show the borders.

Comment: This is not what you want or? (If not, could you include an image of how to result should look like?) `ggplot(shape_df) +
  aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill=factor(var)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  geom_path(color="black")`

Comment: not really but it's my fault...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do this with `sf`, you can use `st_area` to get the area of each polygon (area doesn't make a ton of sense with unprojected toy data, but will make sense with the actual shapes), then order polygons based on area. That way, `ggplot` will create polygons in order by ID. **To use `geom_sf`, you need the [github dev version of `ggplot2`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2)**, though it's being added to the next CRAN release, [slated for next month (July 2018)](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2018/05/ggplot2-2-3-0/).

First create a simple features collection from the data. In this case, I had to use `summarise(do_union = F)` to make each series of points into a polygon in the proper order ([per this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50908771/5325862)), then calculate the area of each.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3

shape_df <- data.frame(
  lon = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0.8, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
  lat = c(0, 0, 1, 1.5, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  var = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 ,3 ,3 ,3 ,3, 4 ,4 ,4, 4, 4)
)

shape_areas <- shape_df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat")) %>%
  group_by(var) %>%
  summarise(do_union = F) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON") %>%
  mutate(area = st_area(geometry)) %>% 
  mutate(var = as.factor(var)) 

shape_areas
#> Simple feature collection with 4 features and 3 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 2 ymax: 2
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>   var do_union area                       geometry
#> 1   1    FALSE 1.25 MULTIPOLYGON (((0 0, 1 0, 1...
#> 2   2    FALSE 1.00 MULTIPOLYGON (((0 1, 1 1, 1...
#> 3   3    FALSE 1.10 MULTIPOLYGON (((1 1, 2 1, 2...
#> 4   4    FALSE 1.00 MULTIPOLYGON (((1 0, 2 0, 2...
```

If I plot at this point, the area has no bearing on the order of plotting; it just orders by `var`, numerically:

```r
shape_areas %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = var), alpha = 0.9)
```

[image]

But if I use `forcats::fct_reorder` to reorder `var` as a factor by decreasing area, polygons will be plotting in order with the largest polygons at the bottom, and smaller polygons layering on top. **Edit:** as @SeGa pointed out below, this was originally putting larger shapes on top. Use `-area` or `desc(area)` to order descending.

```r
shape_areas %>%
  mutate(var = var %>% fct_reorder(-area)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = var), alpha = 0.9)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-30 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: The dev version of `ggplot2`. I mentioned it in the post but I'll link to it

Comment: Could you also include an example with `-area` in the `fct_reorder` function, as the final question asks how to keep larger polygons in the background.

Comment: @SeGa Thank you, you're right—I was misreading the shapes, they were plotting in the reverse order from what I intended

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `fill` but have `alpha=0`, you wont see any colors, as they will be 100% transparent.

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve, as I can see 3 polygons, that you can color differently, not just 2.

What if you try this ggplot-call, which takes the **id** as fill variable (as factor):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = shape_1_2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=factor(id)), 
               colour = 'black', size = 1, linetype = 'solid', alpha = 1)
```

Or this one, which takes **group** as fill variable (as factor) and allows you to define your own colors.

```
ggplot(shape_1_2) +
  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=factor(group)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red", "blue")) +
  geom_path(color="black")
```

[image]

You could also use the `scale_fill_brewer` function, which lets you pick a predefined color palette (show possible palettes with: `display.brewer.all()`)

```
ggplot(shape_1_2) +
  aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill=factor(group)) + 
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdYlGn") +
  geom_path(color="black") +
  ggtitle("fill=factor(group)")
```

Comment: thank you. this works for my example but I just found out that my two example polygons are not nested!

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean with nested. Are they overlaying each other? In your example the polygon with id=0 has a hole, so 2 polygons belong to `id=0`. The group variable finds distinct polygons and each polygon will get a unique color.

Comment: thank you. I updated my question. apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a variable named "aux" to each of the shapes you can use "fill = aux" in ggplot2

You can try to do:

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)

shape_1 <- readShapePoly('poly_1.shp') %>%
fortify()  %>%
mutate(aux = c("1"))

shape_2 <- readShapePoly('poly_2.shp') %>%
fortify()  %>%
mutate(aux = c("2"))

shape_1_2 = rbind(shape_1, shape_2)

ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = shape_1_2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
             colour = 'black', size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', alpha = 0, fill = aux)
```

Comment: Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomPolygon,  : 
  object 'aux' not found

Comment: Sorry... this code need to be: 

geom_polygon(data = shape_1_2, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = aux), 
             colour = 'black', size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', alpha = 0)

Comment: "fill" should be inside of aes