# Spatial Lines based on unique group identifier in R

Tags: r, line, spatial

I have a SpatialPointsDataframe which I have shortened to 4 variables for the purpose of this question. I am looking at bird flight tracks and have sorted the data into unique flight tracks based on timelags to the next point in the sequence.

Points with the same gid(Group ID) are part of a unique flight sequence. I would like all shared gid's to be a separate line string.

[head and tail of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9rf.png)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Use `dput` and publish some of your data. Nobody will help you if you show the data in the picture!

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908771/create-multilines-from-points-grouped-by-id-with-sf-package